# Resizing an image stored as a 'strided' array: can I make this bilinear interpolation faster?

Tags: c, optimization, image-resizing

I have a piece of C code that is part of a public repository ([Darknet](https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet)) which is supposed to resize an image using bilinear interpolation. Because of the way the rest of the code deals with images, the image is stored as a one-dimensional array where the pixel values from the original 3 channel image are read in strides. The value corresponding to pixel `(x, y, k)` (x: column, y: row, k: channel) is thus stored in the location `x + w.h + w.h.c` in the 1D array.

The resize function that is actually part of Darknet is taking a considerable amount of time in the pre-processing stage, possibly because of its nested for loops that iterate over the rows and columns and attempt to access corresponding values, as well as possibly the type conversions: hence I am trying to create a more optimized version of it. The original code for resizing is as follows. `im` is the original image, thus `im.w` and `im.h` are the original width and height. `w` and `h` are the target width and height.

```
image resize_image(image im, int w, int h)
{
    image resized = make_image(w, h, im.c);   
    image part = make_image(w, im.h, im.c);
    int r, c, k;
    float w_scale = (float)(im.w - 1) / (w - 1);
    float h_scale = (float)(im.h - 1) / (h - 1);
    for(k = 0; k < im.c; ++k){
        for(r = 0; r < im.h; ++r){
            for(c = 0; c < w; ++c){
                float val = 0;
                if(c == w-1 || im.w == 1){
                    val = get_pixel(im, im.w-1, r, k);
                } else {
                    float sx = c*w_scale;
                    int ix = (int) sx;
                    float dx = sx - ix;
                    val = (1 - dx) * get_pixel(im, ix, r, k) + dx * get_pixel(im, ix+1, r, k);
                }
                set_pixel(part, c, r, k, val);
            }
        }
    }
    for(k = 0; k < im.c; ++k){
        for(r = 0; r < h; ++r){
            float sy = r*h_scale;
            int iy = (int) sy;
            float dy = sy - iy;
            for(c = 0; c < w; ++c){
                float val = (1-dy) * get_pixel(part, c, iy, k);
                set_pixel(resized, c, r, k, val);
            }
            if(r == h-1 || im.h == 1) continue;
            for(c = 0; c < w; ++c){
                float val = dy * get_pixel(part, c, iy+1, k);
                add_pixel(resized, c, r, k, val);
            }
        }
    }
    free_image(part);
    return resized;
}
```

Is there a way to make this function faster: for instance, by creating a more optimized way to access the pixels instead of this strided read? Also, I note here that in my case:

1. The dimensions of the source and resized images will be fixed, so my 'custom' resize function does not have to be size-independent. I am going from 640x360 to the dimensions 626x352.
2. The target platform is an NVIDIA Jetson with an ARM CPU, so instructions like AVX2 are not applicable in my case. But I do have access to CUDA.

I have to make a note here that because of the requirements of my project, this resize function is actually part of a library (.so) that's being called from Python. So I cannot keep anything "in memory" per se, such as CUDA texture objects etc., so creating them again and again might actually create more overhead on the CUDA side.

Any suggestions in improving this routine would be very helpful.

Comment: Try resampling instead?

Comment: Are you making the new images bigger or smaller?

Comment: @AShelly Smaller: I am going from 640x360 to 626x352.

Comment: `get_pixel` and co are not very effective if you can you should avoid use it, and access `image->data` with only one variable you increment. Image struct should use FAM to increase perf too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[As Stargateur mentioned] `get_pixel` et. al are wasteful.  Most pixel accesses can be handled with a pointer. This is a pretty standard thing to do when processing an image where speed is required.

Most accesses creep along the `x` dimension, so we can just increment pointers.

From `get_pixel`, create this function:

```
static float *loc_pixel(image m, int x, int y, int c)
{
    return &m.data[(c * m.h * m.w) + (y * m.w) + x];
}
```

The `if` in `resize_image` can be moved out of the first inner `for` loop by some restructuring.

In all `for` loops, we can remove all `*_pixel` functions from the inner loop by using `loc_pixel` and pointers.

Here's a refactored version that uses only pointers that should be faster. Note that I've coded this but neither tested nor compiled it. I think it's pretty close, but you should double check to be sure.

One thing you could add that I didn't do is have `loc_pixel` take a *pointer* to the image (i.e. `image *m`) instead of passing the entire struct.

Also, you could experiment with replacing `src[0]` with `src[c]` and `*dst` with `dst[c]`. This would eliminate some `++src` and `++dst` and *might* be faster. It might also allow the compiler to understand the loops better so it could use any arm vector instructions and might make it more amenable to CUDA. YMMV.

```
image
resize_image(image im, int w, int h)
{
    image resized = make_image(w, h, im.c);
    image part = make_image(w, im.h, im.c);
    int r,
     c,
     k;
    float w_scale = (float) (im.w - 1) / (w - 1);
    float h_scale = (float) (im.h - 1) / (h - 1);
    int wm1 = w - 1;
    float val;
    float marg;
    float *src;
    float *dst;

    for (k = 0; k < im.c; ++k) {
        for (r = 0; r < im.h; ++r) {
            src = loc_pixel(im, 0, r, k);
            dst = loc_pixel(part, 0, r, k);
            marg = get_pixel(im, im.w - 1, r, k);

            if (im.w == 1) {
                for (c = 0; c < w; ++c, ++dst)
                    *dst = marg;
                continue;
            }

            for (c = 0; c < wm1; ++c, ++src, ++dst) {
                float sx = c * w_scale;
                int ix = (int) sx;
                float dx = sx - ix;
                val = (1 - dx) * src[0] + dx * src[1];
                *dst = val;
            }

            // handle c == w - 1 case
            *dst = marg;
        }
    }

    for (k = 0; k < im.c; ++k) {
        for (r = 0; r < h; ++r) {
            float sy = r * h_scale;
            int iy = (int) sy;
            float dy = sy - iy;

            src = loc_pixel(part, 0, iy, k);
            dst = loc_pixel(resized, 0, r, k);
            for (c = 0; c < w; ++c, ++src, ++dst) {
                val = (1 - dy) * src[0];
                *dst = val;
            }

            if (r == h - 1 || im.h == 1)
                continue;

            src = loc_pixel(part, 0, iy + 1, k);
            dst = loc_pixel(resized, 0, r, k, val);
            for (c = 0; c < w; ++c, ++src, ++dst) {
                val = dy * src[0];
                *dst += val;
            }
        }
    }

    free_image(part);
    return resized;
}
```

Comment: If you use this technique, I'd be interested to know how the performance compares to the original.

Comment: Very interesting, thank you! The approach with pointers is definitely helping a lot. 

I don't have access to the Jetson right now so I tried this out in a unit test on my desktop. On an average over 100 runs, your version took 2.6ms whereas the original version took 6.1ms per resize op. That is a considerable speedup!

Comment: I am looking into using pointers in the call to loc_pixel. Quick question: is there a reason why you left one get_pixel call in the for loop (marg = get_pixel..) instead of the loc_pixel? Also, do you think hardcoding the source and target dimensions would help in this func?